# OpenID connect mechanism by Fiware Generic Enabler

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect, fiware

I know that Fiware Identity Management called Keyrock provides an oAuth2.0 mechanism for authentication.

Is this mechanism based on OpenId connect profile of OAUth2.0?

Is there any generic enabler for OpenId connect mechanism integration in a Fiware architecture?

I have thought about deploying keycloak in parallel but it would put extra latency on my system and would recude the throughput.

Is there an all in one solution for OAuth2,Openid connect and XACML mechanism providing by fiware?

Should i extend keyrock with an open-id implementation?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Hi! We have just finished the integration of OpenID Connect in Keyrock. The feature is now in a separate branch but we are working on merging it with the master branch. Hopefully it will be ready this week!

Comment: Thank you so much! I am looking forward to using to it. Is there a new section in the documentation about this issue or are you going to update it later?